# Are there higher dimensional equivalents of the Witt Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Witt algebra can be defined by:

$$L_n = -x^{n+1}\frac{d}{dx}$$

Giving the rules:
$$[L_n,L_m] = (n-m)L_{n+m}$$

And there is a central extension called the Virasoro algebra which has a more complicated representation.

It seems fairly straight forward to extend this into a higher dimensions, D. e.g. with $n$ and $x$ d-dimensional vectors:

$$L_{n} = -\prod\limits_{i=1}^d(x_i)^{n_i}\sum_{\mu=1}^dx_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}$$

in which case the rules would be:

$$[L_n,L_m] = \sum_{i=1}^d (n_i-m_i)L_{n+m}$$

I was wondering if there is any use to higher dimensional Witt algebras, and whether they can have central extensions?